# What does 必须追一下 mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

So I found this comment on a drama on YouTube.   Did the commenter mean the person who sang the song (or the theme song itself ) needed to catch up?  Meaning it was not as good as the drama or just something else?

由嘎唱的剧，必须追一下.

It was from this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7VN3rzp9zC4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commenter is expressing his admiration of/affinity towards the singer, 嘎's singing, so in his view, **watching every show** (剧), of which the theme song (主題曲) is sung (唱) by 嘎, **is a must** (必须).

The comment, "watch every show...is a must", reveals a loyal fan's mindset of  "chasing" or "follow closely (緊緊跟隨)" the artist from work to works, so the use of the word "追" (pursue, chase) fits well.

Answer (score 2):

追 has the meaning of "to follow" as in "follow a T.V. drama"  ( loyally watch every episode of the series as they come out)

To follow a TV. series is 追看 (follow and watch) E.g. 很多人都在追'中国好声音'  (Many people are following 'The Voice of China')

To follow a serialized novel is 追閲 (follow and read) E.g. 少時候我有追古龍的小說 (When I was young, I followed the novels written by Gu Long)

> 由嘎唱的剧，必须追一下. -- you must follow (and watch) the drama series that has its theme song sung by Ga

*由嘎唱的剧 -- (the drama series sung by Ga) -- Obviously, he can't sing the drama series, we can presume the comment meant he sung the theme song*

[V] + 一下 = "try to [V]" or "[V] for once"

Answer (score 2):

> 由嘎唱的剧，必须追一下

I figure 嘎 should be the famous singer 阿云嘎 who is very successful in 音乐剧(musical drama). 剧 is referring to **音乐剧，musical**.

So the sentence is saying that *the play(音乐剧) is featured by 嘎, I certainly will see it or follow it.* 追剧 is a common collocation.